# Overhead / problems of creating Realm instances for each operation?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have split my code in many small functions which sometimes are meant to be executed together inside a transaction. So I create somewhere a `Realm` and open a `write` block, and inside this block I call all my functions.

So far I have been passing the `Realm` instance as parameter to the functions in order to be re-used (for calls like `realm.add`), but I wonder if this is really necessary? Does it have any downsides to simply create a new instance of the `Realm` wherever it's needed? I also wonder, in case this is not a problem, if the fact that this new Realm is being used inside a transaction which was "started by" another Realm instance, if maybe this is a problem.

Finally, I also wonder if there may be any problems with the notification token used to suppress executing the notification block for updates - for this, the particular `Realm` instance I use, doesn't matter, right?

P.S. I'm talking only about using `Realm` in the same thread, I'm aware of the multi-thread limitations.

Comment: Which platform are you using Realm on? I assume Swift, given you mentioned blocks?

Comment: @AustinZ Edited! I selected realm-cocoa tag but for some reason StackOverflow ignores it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no harm in passing around `Realm` instances between your functions if you want to structure your code that way. There's also not really any appreciable overhead to opening multiple `Realm` instances on the same thread, since Realm Cocoa has an internal cache that it uses when vending out Realms on the same thread.

I suppose one possible argument against opening `Realm`s repeatedly is that you  must either use `try!`, or wrap each attempt to open a `Realm` in a `do`-`catch` block. In most cases, though, if you've opened a Realm successfully opening it again by creating more `Realm` instances cannot result in file-related errors (as long as you haven't abused Realm by moving the underlying database file).

You also shouldn't need to worry about notification tokens that weren't vended out by a specific `Realm` instance, or using one `Realm` instance within another `Realm` instance's write transaction; if you are indeed working on the same thread Realm should work just fine in the situations you described. (And if it doesn't, please [file a bug](https://github.com/issues) against us!)

More generally speaking, it's better to worry about optimization only if you run into performance issues and Instruments has identified a particular operation as being a potential peformance bottleneck. In your case, I think you can choose whichever solution fits your personal preferences better.